# In C how do you access a variable in a struct that's in a pointer array?

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef struct {
    employeeT *employees;
    int nEmployees;
} *payrollT;

typedef struct {
    string name;
} *employeeT;
```

I need to do this without accessing it as an array:

```
employeeT e = payroll.employees[i];
```

but this gives me an error(expected identifier before '(' token) :

```
employeeT e = payroll.(*(employee+i));
```

before struct's I could interchange employees[i] and *(employee+i)

Comment: Do you seriously not define a type for a non-pointer to that struct?

Comment: If this is homework, please add the "homework" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to avoid array syntax?

`*(ptr+offset) == ptr[offset]`, strictly, every time.

You have NO performance penalty and the array syntax is clearer.

---

EDIT: I just got the real crux of the problem.

If `payroll` (in your example) is a pointer type, you need to use the arrow operator instead of the dot operator:

```
payroll->employees[0]
```

Comment: +1 for your finding of the `->` error. Perhaps you could just invert the two paragraphs of your answer, because the real answer is the second part ;-)

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Heh. I was thrown by the typedef into pointer type... that's something I never use and I think it's a terrible hack that should be outlawed from the standard. :-(

Answer (score 1):

As others noted,

```
employeeT e = *(payroll.employees + i);
```

(or `*(payroll->employees + i)` if `payroll` is a pointer instead of the struct itself) works just fine.

But let's go back to your question; *why* do you think that you can't access `payroll.employees` with the array syntax?  The C standard is perfectly clear on the point that the two expressions are equivalent -- this is actually the definition of the array subscript operator `[ ]` (**§6.5.2.1 Array Subscripting**):

> The definition of the subscript
>   operator [] is that E1[E2] is
>   identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because
>   of the conversion rules that apply to
>   the binary + operator, if E1 is an
>   array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array
>   object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2]
>   designates the E2-th element of E1
>   (counting from zero).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do:

```
employeeT e = *(payroll.employees+i);
```

but what's wrong with the array syntax?  It's certainly clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
employeeT e = *(payroll.employee+i);
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recap the use of `struct`s. Try `*(payroll.employee+i)`.

Edit: Or you can use `(*payroll).employee[i]`.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Yes, and in fact, I prefer the arrow notation for pointers, but I wanted to use the notation which seemed to be more familiar to the questioner.